# how do i get 'get' to be called automatically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multer, ng-file-upload

I am able to add photos and remove them, however when I do so I have to refresh. I would like the scope to be updated and it be done automatically, but after adding files the get never runs. Do I have to use .apply for this?

app.js

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  if ($scope.file) {
    $scope.upload($scope.file);

  }

  if($scope.files){
    $scope.uploadFiles($scope.files);
    console.log('this happens after upload files');
  }
};

 $scope.uploadFiles = function (files) {

  if (files && files.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      Upload.upload({
        url: 'api/admin/photos',
        data: {files: files[i]}
      }).then(function(resp){
        $scope.photos.push(resp.data);
        $log.info(resp.data);
        $log.info($scope.photos);
        getPhotos();
      },
      function(resp){
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
      },
      function(evt){
        //var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
         //console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.files.name);
      });
    }
  }

};



   //get all photographs
   $scope.photos = [];
   var getPhotos = function(){

$http.get('api/admin/photos/get')
    .then(function successCallback(response){
        $scope.photos.length = 0;
        for (var i=0; i < response.data.length; ++i){
            $scope.photos.push(response.data[i]);
        }
        $log.warn($scope.photos);
        console.log('this happened automatically');
    },
    function errorCallback(error){
        $log.warn(error);
    });
```

};

```
getPhotos();

$scope.deletePics = function(id){

    $http.delete('/api/admin/photos/' + id, {params : {id: id}})
        .then(function successCallback(response){
            //console.log(response);
            $scope.photos = $scope.photos.filter(function(photo){
             return photo.id !== id;
          });
            },
            function errorcallback(error){
                console.log(error);
            });

  };
```

When I submit for upload, in my console.log this is what I'm getting:

```
[Object, Object]0: Object1: Objectlength: 2__proto__: Array[0]
```

app.js:375 this happened automatically

[image]

However, when I refresh the code, images show up.

HTML

```
<form  ng-controller="adminController" name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">


Single Image with validations
```

Select
  submit

```
<span class="progress" ng-show="progress >= 0">
        <div style="width:{{progress}}%" ng-bind="progress + '%'"></div>
    </span>

</form>


<ul >
    <li ng-repeat="photo in photos"><img ng-src="img/{{ photo.url}}" />

    {{ photo }}
    {{photo.name}}

    {{photos}}

     <button class="button btn btn-warning" ng-      click="deletePics(photo._id)">Delete</button>
 </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: If `Upload` does not use `$http` service then yes.

Comment: So put it in a method and call the method after the Ajax call is made.

Comment: @epascarello This will add additional request to refetch all the data that are already on the client.

Comment: Ok, I did that, and now in my console.log I am seeing the object. Now I have an array of objects which is fine, however I cannot see it in the view. It is undefined. Maybe this is a different scope?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko so where is your answer that does not make the call? Yes the OP could push the data onto the array, but does that guarantee the server has it?

Comment: the server has it, thats not the problem. The problem is the client doesnt update. Actually as of now the client in console.log shows the objects [Object, Object]0: Object1: Objectlength: 2__proto__: Array[0]
app.js:376 this happened automatically but not seeing anything in the view.

Comment: So did you call $scope.apply() like I mentioned in a comment below? Did it force the view to update with the new data?

Comment: do i just wrap $scope.$apply around the get? I'm not sure how it's done.

Comment: you should use `$log.warn` everywhere instead of `console.log`. Just in case one day you want to unit test it.

Comment: @epascarello You are right. I have deleted my answer since it is hard to say if it is ok simply push/remove data without knowing the context.

Comment: I posted an answer below, but I would just add this, have your post to api/admin/photos return back the photo that was inserted(the metadata for it), then just push that to $scope in your .then(), saves a trip to the db, would only update if the upload was successful (200 OK, 201 OK)

Answer (score 3):

simply your get into a function that you will call into your `then()`

```
$scope.photos = [];
//get all photographs
var getPhotos = function(){
    $http.get('api/admin/photos/get')
        .then(function successCallback(response){
            $scope.photos.length = 0;
            for (var i=0; i < response.data.length; ++i){
                $scope.photos.push(response.data[i]);
            }
        },
        function errorCallback(error){
            $log.warn(error);
        });

};
getPhotos(); // That way it is still called
```

.

```
 $scope.uploadFiles = function (files) {

  if (files && files.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      Upload.upload({
        url: 'api/admin/photos',
        data: {files: files[i]}
      }).then(function(resp){
        $scope.photos.push(resp.data);
      },
      function(resp){
         console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
         getPhotos();              // <==== Here
      },
      function(evt){
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
         console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.files.name);
      });
    }
  }

};
```

Comment: `function getPhotos = function(){` a typo. And this would refetch data from the server that were already on the client and finally cause digest loop. Why not call it manually without additional request?

Comment: This worked, in terms of getting anything in. However now in my console.log I am seeing the object in array, however when in the view in ng-repeat I cannot see the array. Maybe the scope is not the same scope?

Comment: [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
length: 7

Comment: @arsenalist if you call `$scope.$apply()` after you upload the files, does it update the view?

Comment: When I do your solution, it adds the objects but doest not reflect in the view. However, when I refresh, everything shows in the view , strange.

Comment: @arsenalist I've updated the "getPhotos" function. Can you try the changes?

Comment: I've tried them.  For some reason still, in console log i can see the objects but in the view i have to refresh to see the pictures.

Comment: can you also update your question, adding a small piece of your view code? (and tell me when it's done)

Comment: @arsenalist by view code, I was meaning the html code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101714/discussion-between-arsenalist-and-deblaton-jean-philippe).

Answer (score 0):

```
     $scope.uploadFiles = function (files) {

      if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          Upload.upload({
            url: 'api/admin/photos',
            data: {files: files[i]}
          }).then(function(resp){
            //$scope.photos.push(resp.data);
     $scope.getPhotos().then(function(response){
            $scope.photos = response.data;
        },
        function errorCallback(error){
            $log.warn(error);
        });
          },
          function(resp){
            console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
          },
          function(evt){
            var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
             console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.files.name);
          });
        }
      }

    };



    //get all photographs
    $scope.getPhotos = function(){

      return $http.get('api/admin/photos/get');
    }

    $scope.getPhotos().then(function(response){
            $scope.photos = response.data;
        },
        function errorCallback(error){
            $log.warn(error);
        });

    $scope.deletePics = function(id){

        $http.delete('/api/admin/photos/' + id, {params : {id: id}})
            .then(function successCallback(response){
                },
                function errorcallback(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });

      };
```